# Mongo Upgrade 4.4 to 5

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade mongodb standalone ver 4.4.22 to 5.

I have stopped the services, made the `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-5.0.repo` directory, installed the yum packages with `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org` command and started the services, however, the MongoDB version is still 4.4.22

Need some help

//UPDATE
The issue has been resolved. Had to yum install the packages specifically.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-standalone/